# Draw the curve by tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, curve-fitting, control

[image]

I want to draw a curve using controls (in picture). Please, everybody help me!

Comment: welcome to tex.se! this site usual doesn't provide service "do-this-instead-me" ... show us, what you try so far and where you stuck in your effort.

Comment: What is the function describing the curve?

Comment: You can see code exxamples online [Here!](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parameterized-plots/), if you cant find what you want, try to put some minimun working example (MWE), to get some help or see the related answers...

Comment: What do you mean 'using controls'?

Comment: @cfr I'm wondering if (s)he is referring to Bezier control points...

Answer (score 1):

You can play with `in` and `out`. To obtain as smooth curve, you only make sure that the `in` and `out` parameters of two successive points differ by 180. And using looseness you can further control the shape of the curve.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[gray] (-1,-3) grid (9,4);
\draw[thick,-latex] (-1,0) -- (9,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\draw[thick,-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,4) node[below right]{$y$};
\draw[thick,blue] (0,0) to[out=-70,in=180] (1.2,-1.5) 
to [out=0,in=180,looseness=0.4] (5.8,3.9) to[out=0,in=120,looseness=0.5] (8,0);
\node[anchor=north west] at (5,0) {5};
\node[anchor=north east] at (0,0) {0};
\node[anchor=south east] at (0,1) {2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```